# Magento 2 - Custom theme - Change the background to an image

Tags: magento2, image, dashboard, code

I know how to change the colour of my background in my custom theme however I was wondering if it were possible to change the background on all pages to an image?

I imagine it is similar to changing the colour but I don't know enough about magento 2 to be able to do it.

Any help would be much appreciated. I understand that my question is vague and basic ;)

Comment: Can you add more description to your question?

Comment: I've added more now. I appreciate that my question is very basic :P

Comment: Do you want same image on all pages? Can you provide the image size or image?

Comment: Just an image that covers the whole background. Something you would make in photoshop maybe rather than having the background as one solid colour like #FFC0CB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this in one of your css / less files:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../images/image.png');
}
```

and place the `image.png` file in the relative path to your file mentioned above.

Comment: Would the path be something like app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/web/images/picture.png ?